# parent.window with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#thelink').click(function(){
$('div#thedialog').dialog('open'); 
});
```

How do i change this to open window.parent´s div #thedialog.. can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
window.parent.$('div#thedialog').dialog('open');
```

That assumes that the parent window has pulled in its own copy of jQuery, of course.  It might also work to do this:

```
$(window.parent).find('div#thedialog').dialog('open');
```

but I personally am pretty cautious about setting up stuff in one window using code that lives in another one. IE tends to get pretty freaky about that sometimes.

Comment: Well, if it's not too much trouble, would you mind elaborating on exactly what the problem is?

Comment: Oh its working.. the first one, but not the second with find(), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but the answer provided by Pointy will only work if *thedialog* div is visible by parent window directly. If you have *thedialog* div inside the frame and you want to display the dialog on the main window, you have to add a frame's document reference to jQuery selector (which is executed in top window's scope) like so

$(window.parent).find('div#thedialog', **thedialogframe.document**).dialog('open');